# How can I modify the Edge logo on the taskbar when launching via VDI? the edge is hosted on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, horizon, vdi

How can I modify the Edge logo on the taskbar when launching via VDI? the edge is hosted on Windows Server 2019.

The Edge application is hosted on Windows 2019 and published through Horizon VDI. I have customized the Edge icon on the Windows 2019 server, and when I launch Edge from within the server, the logo appears as the customized one that I changed. However, when I launch Edge through Horizon VDI, the customized logo does not appear as expected.